# Microsoft Graph - AddOwner API does not let me add an Application as group owner

Tags: javascript, python, azure, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

I'm using Microsoft Graph API Beta version to add an application as owner of a group (I verified this is possible via Azure Console).
The API I found for my case is this one: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/group-post-owners?view=graph-rest-beta&tabs=javascript#example.
However, it seems the API is made to support the adding of users but not applications as group owners.
In fact, the error message I get is the following:

```
{'error': {'code': 'Request_BadRequest', 'message': "The reference target 'Application_xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx' of type 'Application' is invalid for the 'owners' reference.", 'innerError': {'date': '2021-11-30T10:07:24', 'request-id': 'xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx', 'client-request-id': 'xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx'}}}
```

How can I solve this issue?
I absolutely need the application to be a group owner in order to add the group to an access package catalog.

Thank you.

Comment: Hello @AlessandroDeVitis , the API you are using is for adding owner of MS teams group. May I know if you are trying for the same ? And if you are trying for group owner of AAD group then you need to use this [API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/group-post-owners?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http) and instead of `users` in the body you can try using `directoryObjects`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried in my environment .Please refer the request shown below to add application as owner to AAD Group as refered by @Ansuman.
But by using `directoryObjects` instead of users and by using `Objectid of service principal` of the application.

(You can get svp ObjectId by searching with  the application id in enterprise applications.There the object Id is different from actual object id of application in appregistrations overview).

You may refer this  [Service Principal objects in Azure Active Directory](https://raaviblog.com/where-to-find-application-and-service-principal-objects-in-azure-active-directory/)

This is the Request:

```
POST https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/groups/<GroupObjectID>/owners/$ref
Content-type: application/json
{
    "@odata.id": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/directoryObjects/<ObjectIdOfServicePricipalOfApplication>"
}
```

[image]

Could see the owner of group named TESTsecuritygroup as web app :

[image]

Comment: Thank you! I didn't know the same application could have two different object id in App Registrations and Enterprise Applications.
Now it's working :)